# Check File Size on Upload in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, upload

When uploading a file via the Visualforce `apex:inputFile` standard component, if the file size exceeds the 3Mb limit I would like to display a message to the user that the file is greater than 3Mb and cannot be uploaded into the system.
Please advise how this can be achieved on VisualForce level?

Comment: @ Sebastian, so far I've tried the script in the following article: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.bg/2014/09/check-file-size-on-upload-in-visualforce.html?m=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just bind fileSize to an attribute:

```
public Integer fileSize { get; set; }
// ...
if(fileSize > 3000000) {
  // Show error
  return;
}
```

---

```
<apex:inputFile filesize="{!fileSize}" ... />
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be  3 * 1024 * 1024? so `if(fileSize > 3145728)`

Comment: @caleb.breckon I personally prefer the classic definition of kilo/mega/giga (base-2 notation), but Salesforce tends to use the IEC standard definitions (notice we have a 6000000 byte heap limit, not 6291456 bytes). It's really a matter of who's asking.

Comment: @sfdcfox do we have any limitation for this. I have exactly used this but I am gettng filesize null in submit function called through action function  on apex side. The function has return type of pageReference. I am really stuck there !

Comment: @PankajAndhale It depends on the situation. apex:inputFile does not support rerendering, so you need to be aware of the limitations. You may want to ask a specific question with your code so we can take a look.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you  for responding. I am not using rendering. That is a different headache though. I checked again for different scenarios. Only if the file size is exceeding 25 mb, then it is making this filesize variable as 0.

Comment: @PankajAndhale Maybe a bug? I know there is a maximum payload size, it may be that Visualforce is not even attempting the file since it exceeds some limit.